# How to authorize bintray api

Tags: java, api, maven, curl, bintray

here bintray doc say:

> The Bintray REST API requires an applicative API key. An API key can be >obtained from the user profile page. Authentication is achieved using HTTP >Basic Authentication with the user’s name as username and the API key as >the password. Authenticated REST calls should only be used via HTTPs.

I don't understand "HTTP >Basic Authentication", how to do it in linux `curl`?

Answer (score 1):

add the arugments **--basic** and **-u username:api_key** to the curl command... basic authentication is an unencrypted way to send an authorization header with your HTTP request

Answer (score 0):

For example, to upload file:

```
curl -SvT POST \
FILE \
--user "$BINTRAY_USER:$BINTRAY_KEY" \
https://api.bintray.com/content/organization/repository/package/$version/
```

For publish all files in the same version location, use the following command:

```
curl -SvX POST \
--user "$BINTRAY_USER:$BINTRAY_KEY" \
https://api.bintray.com/content/organization/repository/package/$version/publish
```

To get signed_url:

Linux:

```
curl -SvX POST \
https://api.bintray.com/signed_url/organization/repository/FILE?encrypt=false \
--user "$BINTRAY_USER:$BINTRAY_KEY" \
-H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
-H 'content-type: application/json' \
-d '{"expiry": "4000000000000"}'
```

Win (you may use 'k' option to skip cert verification):

```
curl -SkvX POST ^
https://api.bintray.com/signed_url/organization/repository/FILE?encrypt=false ^
--user "%BINTRAY_USER%:%$BINTRAY_KEY%" ^
-H "cache-control: no-cache" ^
-H "content-type: application/json" ^
-d "{"expiry": "4000000000000"}"
```